# How do I map <properties> by code with NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I need to define a unique constraint on multiple properties. In XML this would look like:

```
<properties name="Name" unique="true">
  <property name="FirstName" />
  <property name="LastName" />
</properties>
```

What is the mapping-by-code equivalent in NHibernate (3.3+)? Are there any alternatives to create a multi-column unique index?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to create a unique index is the following:

```
this.Property(x => x.FirstName, m => m.UniqueKey("name"));
this.Property(x => x.LastName, m => m.UniqueKey("name"));
```

I still have not found out how to map `<properties>`, though.